# Como alterar cor do background

Tags: android

Queria alterar a cor do background de uma atividade, ja vi alguns topicos aqui mas sem sucesso.
Ao selecionar no spinner sera mudado a cor da atividade para preto, ou branco.
Como faço para alterar as cores?

Comment: esta pergunta foi respondida no SOen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20032594/android-need-to-change-the-spinner-background-color

Comment: @Thallyson, não é a mesma coisa. A pergunta do SO EN troca o background do Spinner, não da Activity.

Comment: Isso, não quero trocar da spinner, e sim do background da atividade

Comment: Tentei colocar LinearLayout li=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);
      li.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
       li.invalidate();     Mas sem sucesso trava, e da nullPointException

Comment: Se a troca for estática (um número fixo apenas), você pode criar um Tema que extenda o tema da aplicação, onde varia apenas o atributo `android:background`, setando conforme a escolha (`SharedPreferences` p.e). Eu costumo usar a solução do tema, porque ofereço apenas dois temas pro usuário nas configurações do app. Como dá `NPE`? o `li` é nulo? Inclua o código que gera erro e o `stacktrace` se puder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer dessa maneira

[image: view]

Adicionar um id na sua view 
e depois pegar a view na sua activity e setar a cor
[image: activity]

Comment: Para criar blocos de código, você pode utilizar o botão `{}` acima da caixa de edição.

Comment: vlw, não sabia disso

Comment: Perfeito! Como animar a mudança? Eu vi um topico sobre o TransictionDrawable, porem nao consegui, se puder complementar sua resposta como animar, agradeço muito

Comment: Tentei colocar isso: TransitionDrawable transition = (TransitionDrawable) view.getBackground();
     transition.startTransition(1000); porem da esse erro: E/AndroidRuntime(1689): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-18 22:39:48.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1689): Process: com.example.exercicio, PID: 1689
09-18 22:39:48.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1689): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable

Answer (score 0):

ou usando cores rgb no LinearLayout

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
**android:background="#ffffff"**>
```